# Kotlin: Unresolved reference: ofInstant

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to compile an open source code, that is written in Kotlin. The build using gradle is failing with error:

> Unresolved reference: ofInstant

This is the line that is causing the error:

```
package common.time
import java.time.*
private val UTC = ZoneId.of("UTC")
fun Instant.toUtcLocalDate() = LocalDate.ofInstant(this, UTC)
```

I have the latest JDK installed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `this`? The `ofInstant` method takes an `Instant` object as a parameter. Unless you're working on the actual Java standard library, `this` cannot be an `Instant` because it's a final class.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question with full code

Comment: Ah, of course. An extension function :)

Answer (score 1):

`LocalDate.ofInstant()` is only in Java 9 and later. You can use `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(this, UTC).toLocalDate()` instead.

Comment: I have JDK 14 installed. I have updated Java using update utility. Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: The available standard library is also based on the target SDK you have set for your project, which you can set in the project settings.

Comment: I found the issue, I have two JAVA_PATH variables set. One at user level and on at system level. User lever variable is pointing to old JDK